# How can this paradox be resolved?

Tags: puzzle, paradoxes

I came up with a (probably unoriginal) paradox today, and was wondering how it might be resolved.  Its approach to reasoning seems to resemble basic game theory techniques.

Suppose a casino game has an expected return rate of over 100% of the cost to play (in other words, the game is profitable long term).  A player would want to play the game repeatedly, and continue to gain profit.  However, due to the variance in the outcome of each individual round, the question is raised, "how much starting capital is needed to play this game and not go bankrupt, with probability P% (i.e., a 95% chance of not going bankrupt, or 99%, or whatever percentage the player is comfortable with)?"

Now suppose that for whatever value of P the player selects, math or simulation is used to determine that 21 USD is the minimum required starting capital to achieve that desired level of safety.  Having only 20 USD is insufficient (only whole USD are used in the game).  If we assume that the outcome of each round is independent of the last, it follows that when a new round begins, if the player's current capital is 20 USD or less, then the player should stop playing.

However, once the player knows that he or she will walk away if at or below 20 USD, it becomes irrational to play the game with a starting capital of 21-40 USD.  The probability of not going bankrupt should now be calculated as the probability of not declining to 20 USD capital (which we can call P'), as this will now be the trigger for the player to walk away from the game forever (comparable to true bankruptcy, with a 20 USD offset).  P' will be very low (we might expect far less than 50%) when the starting capital is 21 USD, and P' at 40 USD will be equal to what P was at 20 USD.

Therefore you should not play the game with a starting capital of less than 41 USD.  But then it also becomes irrational to play the game at 41-60 USD, because P'' is now the relevant probability to consider, and for that range, it is unacceptably low.

Continue with this pattern indefinitely.

The conclusion of the paradox seems to be that it is not rational to play any such casino game with a profitable expected return rate, if you desire any specific probability of success (whether it is 51%, 95%, 99%, etc.), and have any finite starting capital.  Of course, this is absurd.  Can anyone find a solution to this paradox?

Comment: I think this is the St. Petersburg paradox.

Comment: One of the possible problems is simply in the way this game is set up. For any game where the probability of winning a round is <1, and the player plays indefinitely, they will *always* eventually end up bankrupt. If you were to change the parameters, however, such that the player would leave the game if they won a certain amount, or they would only play a maximum number of rounds, then you would have solved this as well.

Comment: @mardat I don't think this is true. See for instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17999/1d-random-walk-probability-to-go-back-to-origin

Comment: I don't think this is the St. Petersburg paradox.  That paradox is for games with an infinite expected return rate.

Comment: I think you need to be more precise with the gambling odds, it does matter if there is 1/3 th chance on USD 4 or an 1/300 th chance on USD 400, the first is probably playable, but the second probably not , but both have the same average payaout.

Comment: In an infinite one-dimension random walk, one is guaranteed to eventually visit (an infinite number of times) every integer on the number line. The problem with casinos is that there is a wall at zero that excludes negative numbers, and so you will eventually lose. On the other hand, If you start with an infinite amount of money, it is guaranteed that you will eventually make a profit (of any amount you desire), *provided* the games are unbiased.

Comment: @Marconius this is true only when walking left/right with 50/50 probability

Comment: There are several questionable steps here. For example, the argument assumes that anyone who cannot tolerate a probability $q$ of going bankrupt also cannot tolerate a probability $q$ of losing a dollar and then quitting. Going bankrupt and losing one dollar out of $21$ you possess are two very different outcomes, so it seems silly to assume someone would be equally averse to both.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about the "Kelly Criterion."  If you are playing a game that you are favored to win, but is not a certainty, you would never wager your entire endowment because there is a "risk of ruin."  The Kelly Criterion establishes the rate you should bet to maximize your long-run growth rate.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a paradox because your interpretation of the bankruptcy condition changes part of the way through your argument, especially when you say *"once the player knows that he or she will walk away if at or below 20 USD, it becomes irrational to play the game with a starting capital of 21-40 USD"*.  But there are at least two ways of avoiding this.

- You could stop betting when the money you hold is positive but less than or equal to the minimum stake, i.e. you never bet enough that an adverse outcome in the next round reduces your holding to $0$ or less.  If this leads to you stopping, then you are not bankrupt even though you may have lost money.  This seems to be David K's point.
- You could take to the casino an amount your are prepared to lose (leaving your main savings at home) in exchange for the positive overall expectation and the possibility of winning a potentially unlimited amount if you are willing to stay in the casino long enough

Taking the second possibility, let's suppose that each independent round gives you a $46.27\%$ chance of losing your stake and a $53.73\%$ chance of winning the same amount.  That gives you a net expected gain of $7.46\%$ of your stake each round.  Now let's suppose you go to the casino with $\$N$ and you decide to bet $\$1$ each time until you either lose all the money you started with or you gain some arbitrarily large amount (e.g. $\$1000$ or $\$1000000$ or whatever you have time for).  We can now work out the probabilities that you lose all your initial $\$N$ before hitting your target gain, for some different starting amounts (the formulae for the [gambler's ruin with a biased coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#Unfair_coin_flipping) are well known):

```
 N  probability of losing it all 
 1      0.8612
 2      0.7416
 3      0.6386
 4      0.5500
 5      0.4736
10      0.2243
20      0.0503
21      0.0433
40      0.0025
41      0.0022
```

So here the probability of losing everything is just over $5\%$ if $N=20$ and under  $5\%$ if $N=21$.  With $N=40$ you can square that to give just over $0.25\%$, and lower if $N=41$.

So the player in fact knows that starting with $\$21-40$ and following this strategy gives a probability of leaving with a very large amount of over $95\%$ (a satisfactory position in terms of how you began your question), and starting with $\$41$ or more gives a very high probability (an even more desirable position).

There is no paradox here so long as the player can tolerate a small risk of losing; if you are unwilling to contemplate any loss then you should not visit a casino at all.