# Random walk and Gambler's Ruin

Tags: probability, random-variables, random-walk

i stumbled upon this lecture notes regarding solving Gambler's Ruin problem "https://web.mit.edu/neboat/Public/6.042/randomwalks.pdf", and the lecturer concluded that

> pn = (p/ 1-p)^m

after linear recurrence of

> pn = pPn+1 + (1 − p)Pn−1

where "n" start amount of money , "m" is the amount of dollars you want to win . T = n+m.

In another source , it stated The probability of being at position m after N jumps is therefore given a bionomial distribution equation.

Which one is right ?!

Comment: $P_n$ in the lecture notes denotes the probability of loosing $n$ dollars before winning $m$ dollars. It is very different from the probability of reaching $m$ dollars after $N$ plays (since in that model, you do not consider the idea of going broke, i.e. you assume that you can borrow unlimited amounts of money).

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch could you please elaborate more , i still can't get my head around it !

Comment: **For $P_n$:** You start with $n$ dollars, you bet $1$ dollar each round, you win with probability $p$ and loose with probability $1-p$. You play until you either loose $n$ dollars (go broke) or win $m$ dollars. The probability that you leave the Casino in the "lucky case" of having won $m$ dollars is $P_n$.

**For the binomial distribution:** If nobody cares about going broke or about stopping after winning any amount of money, the distribution of your capital after $N$ rounds will be a binomial distribution.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch thanks a lot for the help. so I can use the binomial distribution equation as a general equation to determine any position after N steps. Right?

one last thing please, if I want to calculate probability back to the origin , i can use the bionmial equation, or can i use p(2n=0) = 2n choose n / 2^2n ?

Comment: Do you mean the probability of ever returning to the start (i.e. capital $=n$) when you have a downwards drift?

Comment: yes , are either of the above-mentioned equations be used ?

Comment: No it is not, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/18015/631742) for a derivation for a formula answering your question about the "probability of return to the origin."